# How to set logout automatically in PHP after session ends

Tags: php, session-variables

Please do not mark this as duplicate just by looking at the title. I've seen some post related to this. But couldn't find one matching my query.

I am creating a web-site with user login. On the index page I've set

```
session_set_cookie_params(7200);
```

so that the session will be active for 2 hours even if browser is closed. But I want the user to be logged out after 2 hours.

I have created the website so that user can login anytime and it will stay for 2 hours. But how to modify it so that page is available for two hours fixed, say (9-11 am) regardless of when the user logs in the time between?

Comment: Set the cookie to expire at that time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save in your database the login time of the user.

Compare then the current time with the login time and see if it's more than two hours.

If so, perform the logout.

---

Pseudocode:

```php
$currentDate = date('U');
$loginDate   = $dateComingFromTheDatabase; // UNIX timestamp

if (($currentDate - $loginDate) >= 7200)
{
    PerformLogout();
}
```